# Embed widgets in Jupyter markdown

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-widget

I'm trying to compose a table (markdown or html) which contains a Jupyter widget - a button on each row. I've tried outputting bits of HTML using display(HTML(...)) but it renders everything in its own div thus ruining the table.